# HTML DOM Events with Visual Website Optimizer

Tags: jquery, dom, optimization

I trying to ge a AB-test working on a site and I’m not able to edit anything at the original variation and I want to but a custom conversion goal at a fake control page and at the variation page.

If I request an external js-file with the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lLink a').attr("onclick", "if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) == 'function') { _vis_opt_goal_conversion(204); _vis_opt_pause(500);}");
});
```

Everything works fine. If I remove the external resource and try to do it within VWO it doesn’t work.

So what I’m trying to do is to put a custom conversion goal on a link. I what to do this with the following in the add css/js option:

```
vwo_$('.lLink a').attr("onclick", "if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) == 'function') { _vis_opt_goal_conversion(204); _vis_opt_pause(500);}");
```

Im running the test and nothing happens.

I then tried to do the same thing at the site from the console, nothing.

Again in the console I tired
`vwo_$('.lLink a').attr("WHATEVER", "if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) == 'function') { _vis_opt_goal_conversion(204); _vis_opt_pause(500);}");`

And it worked.

So what is the problem with VWO and the HTML DOM Events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are not waiting for the DOM to get ready in case of adding it to the Add JS/CSS option. So please use the following code inside the Add JS/CSS option:

```
vwo_$(function() {
    vwo_$('.lLink a').attr("onclick", "if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) == 'function') { _vis_opt_goal_conversion(204); _vis_opt_pause(500);}");
});
```

Comment: That sounds weird since I'm able to manipulate the DOM with something like `vwo_$('.lLink a').attr("WHATEVER", "if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) == 'function') { _vis_opt_goal_conversion(204); _vis_opt_pause(500);}");` and it works.

Comment: I believe you will be doing that after page is loaded using the developer console which will work as the DOM would have been ready. Also not in all cases the VWO code will execute after DOM load, being asychronous its timing cannot be determined, hence DOM ready is best suited to make sure elements are found on the page.